# How can I get cookies specifically for a subdomain in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, subdomain

I'm running into an issue with getting the right cookies for the current subdomain. I have two different instances of the same application, one running at the `www` subdomain and the other running at the `test` subdomain, but it seems like the test app is pulling in cookies from the `www` instead, even if there are explicit cookies for `.test.domain.com` (because it's different instances the same application, the cookie name is the same, but I am not looking to share sessions or cookies between the two instances).

Is there any way to specify what domain Rails should be looking for its cookies for? I have `config.cookies.domain` and `config.action_controller.session[:domain]` both set to `"test.domain.com"` (on the test app), but it doesn't seem to make any difference (and, as well, the cookies being set by the test domain are for some reason ending up with the domain `.test.domain.com` instead of `test.domain.com` and I'm not sure why, or if it's relevant).

**Update:** To make this more complex, I realized I do actually need the dot-prefaced cookie domains (ie. `.test.domain.com` and `.domain.com`), because in general, subdomains *are* supposed to share the main domain's cookies and session (it's only that the test subdomain is actually it's own application rather than being a subdomain of the main application). Obviously `.domain.com` cookies will apply to `test.domain.com`, but is there any way to make the explicitly `test.domain.com` ones take priority?

Comment: What version of rails do you use?

Comment: I'm using Rails 2.3.2 currently.